# Check two columns based on transcoding table - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (I'll call it table_1) like this. The column **CODE_CAT** had been transformed to **COD_CAT_1** based on a transcoded table (I'll call it table_2)

```
CODE    CODE_CAT    COD_CAT_1
=============================
UNT     KXJE6       jE6
UNT     X           NULL
UNT     XI          I
UNT     XM          M
UNT     XeLJ        Alj
UNT     Y           NULL
UNT     fX          NULL
UNT     nX3         3
```

Table_2 looks like this and **CODE_CAT** & **COD_CAT_1** are a concatenation of **CODES_CAT_ORIG** (Original code) and **CODES_CAT_DEST** (destination code) codes.

```
CODES_CAT_ORIG  CODES_CAT_DEST
=======================
3           3
e           A
f           NULL
M           M
Y           NULL
I           I
n           B
J           j
K           S
E           E
L           l
6           6
X           NULL
```

I'm trying to compare **CODE_CAT** and **COD_CAT_1** based on **table_2** and add a new column with **'CASE WHEN'** clause to check if the transformation is OK or NOT.
My desired result will looks like below.

```
CODE    CODE_CAT    COD_CAT_1   CHECK      SHOULD_BE
====================================================
UNT     KXJE6       jE6         NOT OK     SjE6
UNT     X           NULL        OK         NULL
UNT     XI          I           OK         I
UNT     XM          M           OK         M
UNT     XeLJ        Alj         OK         Alj
UNT     Y           NULL        OK         NULL
UNT     fX          NULL        OK         NULL
UNT     nX3         3           NOT OK     B3
```

The logic for **OK and NOt OK** is

For each **CODE_CAT** if all characters have been well transformed in **COD_CAT_1** based on **CODES_CAT_ORIG** and **CODES_CAT_DEST** codes of **table_2**.

For example the first code **KXJE6**, I check if :

```
K => S
X => to nothing ‘’
J => j
E => E
6 => 6
```

If yes then it should be **SjE6** and check is **OK**
If not, then check is **Not OK**

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does " OK or NOT. " mean?

Comment: whats the logic ? you didnt define the logic behind "Ok" and "not OK"

Comment: If the maximum length of `CODE_CAT` is known (let's say 5) you can do 5 left joins to compute this. Otherwise it can be solved with a recursive CTE.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I added the logic in my question :)

Answer (score 2):

It is somewhat simpler if we use `table_2` as *strings* in `TRANSLATE`. I chose `#` character as non-existent and used it in `CASE`'s `NVL` function. See if it helps.

```
SQL> with
  2  ta (code_cat, cod_cat_1) as
  3    (select 'KXJE6', 'jE6' from dual union all
  4     select 'X'    , ''    from dual union all
  5     select 'XI'   , 'I'   from dual union all
  6     select 'XM'   , 'M'   from dual union all
  7     select 'XeLJ' , 'Alj' from dual union all
  8     select 'Y'    , ''    from dual union all
  9     select 'fX'   , ''    from dual union all
 10     select 'nX3'  , '3'   from dual
 11    )
 12  select distinct a.code_cat, a.cod_cat_1,
 13    translate(a.code_cat, '#3eMInJKEL6fYX', '#3AMIBjSEl6') should_be,
 14    case when nvl(a.cod_cat_1, '#') = nvl(translate(a.code_cat, '#3eMInJKEL6fYX', '#3AMIBjSEl6'), '#') then 'OK'
 15         else 'Not OK'
 16    end result
 17  from ta a
 18  order by a.code_cat;

CODE_CAT   COD_CAT_1  SHOULD_BE            RESULT
---------- ---------- -------------------- ------
fX                                         OK
KXJE6      jE6        SjE6                 Not OK
nX3        3          B3                   Not OK
X                                          OK
XeLJ       Alj        Alj                  OK
XI         I          I                    OK
XM         M          M                    OK
Y                                          OK

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```